# What is the cache strategy of TDengine?

Tags: database, tdengine

What is the cache strategy of TDengine? LRU，LFU or others?
How can I config it?
I found some configurations in taos.cfg:

cache
blocks
cacheLast

Answer (score 0):

I think TDengine use LRU as the default cache update policy. Not sure if other strategies are also implemented so not sure if its configurable.